# No map received error while following nav2 tutorial

Tags: navigation, ros2, nav2, ros-iron

I am following [nav2 tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_on_real_turtlebot3.html) with ROS 2 Iron. The /map is published as topic but it does not show at RViz2. What should I do..?

Answer (score 0):

If map is properly published, it should appear in rviz2. Topic can exist (because it is created by the node) but map could not be published. So check if it is really published with

```
ros2 topic echo /map
```

or check the frequency of publishing by `ros2 topic hz /map`

The second common issue is that frame_id in rviz2 is not set properly and the same as map has. It can be checked also using above command inside message (you can check **frame_id** field in map message [map_message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) in *header* and if it's the same as in rviz2.

The third possible solution is that you have some odometry topic problems so there is no transformation between robot and map which means that if you set *frame* in rviz2 to see robot, the map cannot be displayed. Then it is the odometry problem and when fixed, map should be displayed at the same time as robot.